# Show that $f(x)=\frac{2}{x}\cos \frac{1}{x^2}$ is NOT bounded on [-1,1]

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $f(x)=\frac{2}{x}\cos \frac{1}{x^2}$ is NOT bounded on [-1,1]

The hint given in the book:

Let $a_{n} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{(2n-1)\pi }} $

Then $\cos (1/a_{n}^2)=1$ for all n, $a_{n}\rightarrow 0$, and

$\frac{2\cos(1/a_{n}^2)}{a_{n}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{(2n-1)\pi }}}=\sqrt{2(2n-1)\pi }\rightarrow \infty $ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ .

I thought this hint is about the sequential criterion for limits. So, it can only show that $f(x)$ does not have a limit at 0, isn't it? How can I conclude from there that $f(x)$ is not bounded when $x\in[-1,1]$ ?

Comment: what does does it mean for a function to be bounded? Just write it down and you'll see what to do next...you're almost there.

Comment: Sure the hint in the book is based on these $a_n$s?

Comment: The hint constructively shows that in $[-1,1]$ the function takes values as large as you want, which is what they call unbounded.

Comment: One reason it's not bounded on that interval is because it isn't defined everywhere on that interval.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The hint constructively shows that in [−1,1] the function takes the value zero at points as close to zero as you want, which is not what they call being unbounded.

Comment: @did: yep but the fix is easy ($\sqrt{2n\pi}$) so that I would accept the argument :)

Comment: @YvesDaoust I do not think that conveying the message that "everything is fine" when the exercise contains a substantial mistake, is a *service* to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

First, the hint does not give what you wrote, since
$$
\cos (1/a_{n}^2)=\cos\left((2n-1)\frac{\pi}2 \right)=0\neq1,\quad n=1,2,\ldots.
$$ If one sets $b_{n} := \sqrt{\dfrac1{2n\pi }}$, for $n\geq1$, then
$$
\left|f(b_n)\right|=\left|2\sqrt{2n\pi}\cdot\cos (1/b_{n}^2)\right|=\left|2\sqrt{2n\pi}\times 1\right|=2\sqrt{2n\pi},
$$as $n \to \infty$, $b_n \to 0$ and
$$
\left|f(b_n)\right| \to \infty,
$$ thus $f$ is not bounded over $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Since $f(x)=\frac{2}{x}\cos \frac{1}{x^2}$, should it be $\left | f(b_{n}) \right |=\left | 2\sqrt{2n\pi} \right |$ instead? 
Anyway, thanks for the answer. I get the idea now. :)